# How to replace both space and newline form the string using regex

Tags: apex, community, string

```
 lstIQCodes = IQcodeString.replaceAll(' ','').split(',');
```

I have tried the above code and able to replace spaces and now I want to replace newline as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of all the white space, you can just delete it:

```
lstIQCodes = IQcodeString.deleteWhitespace().split(',');
```

ReplaceAll actually takes a regular expression for the first parameter, so the following is also valid:

```
lstIQCodes = IQcodeString.replaceAll('\\s+','').split(',');
```

`\\s` refers to all white space, including tabs, new lines, carriage returns, and spaces.

Or, if you really just wanted spaces and newlines:

```
lstIQCodes = IQcodeString.replaceAll('[\\n ]+','').split(',');
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have recommended as well. Using `split` is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same approach to remove the new lines as well

```
for(String lines : IQcodeString.replaceAll(' ','').split(','))
     system.debug(lines.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample utility function for this specifically because of the presence of the legacy carriage return character (ASCII 13) I was seeing in data.

```
  public static String removeAsciiCharFromString(String str, Integer c) {
    String ret = '';
    List<Integer> chars = new List<Integer>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) != c) {
        chars.add(str.charAt(i));
      }
    }
    ret = String.fromCharArray(chars);
    return ret;
  }
```

Usage:

```
    String test = String.fromCharArray(new List<Integer> { 65, 13, 65 });
    String expected = 'AA';

    String actual = UtilConvert.removeAsciiCharFromString(test, 13);

    System.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Of course you can pass in any ASCII value, such as 32 for whitespace.